# How to obtain accurate accelerometer readings from phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am developing a game and I'm trying to use the accelerometer to detect the amount of push by the user. However, the force applied and the abrupt stopping of the phone imposes an opposite force thus nullifying the applied initial force. How do we refine the accelerometer readings? As of now, I'm getting the readings from an interval of 500 ms to get a delta of the various axis readings but still not able to get a proper solution. Any ideas/examples/suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read the [Accelerometer article on the Windows Phone Team blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/09/08/using-the-accelerometer-on-windows-phone-7.aspx). It covers practical issues such as smoothing accelerometer input:

[image]